# OpenLayers3, WFS ajax request doesn't work

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, ajax

I'm creating a geoportal, which works only on my localhost. I have a problem with adding to my ol.map a vector layer from Geoserver using WFS. I'm using Geoserver v2.7, OL v3.15.1 and jQuery v2.2.4. I had a cross-domain problem, since my gesoerver is hosted at 8080 port and the app is displayed using 9080 port, so I decided to add this layer using JSONP. I added to *geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml* the following code:

> ```
>  <context-param>
>  <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
>  <param-value>true</param-value>
>  </context-param>
> ```

Here's my code for adding a layer through AJAX request:

```
   var vectorLoader = function() {
   $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows',{
     type: 'GET',
     data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '2.0.0',
      request: 'GetFeature',
      typename: 'brzesko:wydarzenia',
      srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
      outputFormat: 'application/json',
      bbox: '2293539.9663390242,6439346.050046678,2294549.5570354667,6442264.769222975'
     },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'loadFeatures',
     jsonp:'format_options'
     });
   };
  var geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();  
  var loadFeatures = function(response) {
   vectorSource.addFeatures(geoJSON.readFeatures(response));
  };
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: geoJSON,
    loader: vectorLoader
  });

  var wydarzenia= new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource (...)
```

(can't use *outputFormat:'text/javascript'*, my WFS doesn't support it...)
Then I get an error in the console.log:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?(...)

However, when I open the link in new tab I get a working JSON with all features and information. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've seen several similar posts but none of the given solutions works for me.